# How to make springboot app run on -Xmx450m this jvm param throws OutOfMemoryError , currently its not comming below -Xmx1000m in heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am trying to run my springboot on memory constraint machine of heroku-free.
Heroku says you need to keep you -Xmx300m, but we can pass parameter till 512m as that is the upper limit.

The problem is that i am stuck, no matter how minimal i make my app it needs postgrese and redis connection and its using ateleast -Xmx1000m, i even tried some variation with introducing some GC still no luck. Below are the jvm params needed curretly to make my app work,(note:i haven't done any stress testing):

```
-Xmx1000m -Xms384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC
```

i have even given added `server.tomcat.max-threads = 1` in `application.properties` no luck.

I need to run my app on below jvm params, Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
-Xmx450m -Xms384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

With the above jvm param,app starts but if you make any api hit  throws below error
UPDATE:

```
   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:77) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingRequestWrapper.<init>(ContentCachingRequestWrapper.java:88) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:281) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at com.app.x.security.JwtTokenFilter.doFilter(JwtTokenFilter.java:46) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
```

further i was able to drill down to HeadWritterFilter.class this is part of springSecurity token verification

```
void writeHeaders(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Iterator var3 = this.headerWriters.iterator();  //there are 5 values here
while(var3.hasNext()) {
    HeaderWriter writer = (HeaderWriter)var3.next();
    writer.writeHeaders(request, response);             //fails on the last value
}
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error might help

Comment: Without knowing why your application is running out of memory, it is very hard to help you. Something could be creating a huge `ByteArrayOutputStream` or it could be something else entirely that’s almost filled up the heap.

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace. Something is reading a large blob of data in-memory instead of directly streaming it. So I assume this is your own user code that is leading to the issue (reading large chunks of data in-memory instead of directly streaming it to the client.

Comment: @M.Deinum i have added the stack trace, and the function where its faiing

Comment: @AndyWilkinson i have addded the stack trace and the location where it fails

Comment: The error occurs when caching the request body. Did you include a filter to write the request to the log? Judging by the fact you have a `AbstractRequestLoggingFilter` in there I would say yes. I would suggest removing that from the chain.

Comment: @M.Deinum you were right, i had followed https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging
public class RequestLoggingFilterConfig {
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter
          = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
        filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        filter.setIncludePayload(true);
        filter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000);
        filter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
        filter.setAfterMessagePrefix("REQUEST DATA : ");
        return filter;
    }
}

above was the root cause

Answer (score 0):

Root cause was logging
@M.Deinum you were right, i had followed https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging

```
public class RequestLoggingFilterConfig {
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter
          = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
        filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        filter.setIncludePayload(true);
        filter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000);
        filter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
        filter.setAfterMessagePrefix("REQUEST DATA : ");
        return filter;
    }
}
```